# Simplifying a recursive fraction involving Lambert function

Tags: fractions, recursion, lambert-w

Is there a simplification for the following recursive fraction :

$$\frac{\frac{\frac{n}{W(n)}}{W\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}\right)}}{W\left(\frac{\frac{n}{W(n)}}{W\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}\right)}\right)}$$

The above formula uses a recursion 3 times. I'm looking for a simplification when we have such a finite recursion, for instance when this one appears $i$ times. I would like to remove the recursion, i.e. obtain a single fraction.

Thank you.

Comment: The question is unclear.  What is it that you mean by "simplifying"?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thank for your comment. I mean "reducing to a single fraction", without any recursion, using simple terms (except the Lambert function). Post edited ! :-)

Comment: Since $W(n)\approx\log(n)-\log\log(n)$ for large $n$s, I doubt there is any substantial simplification. What is the source of this problem?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio This a problem of mine but, in fact, I'm wondering if there exists a result on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u=W(u)e^{W(u)}$, it follows that $\frac u{W(u)}=e^{W(u)}$ and we get

$$\frac{\frac{\frac{n}{W(n)}}{W\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}\right)}}{W\left(\frac{\frac{n}{W(n)}}{W\left(\frac{n}{W(n)}\right)}\right)}=e^{W\left(e^{W(e^{W(n)})}\right)}$$

Which is the best simplification I can see.

Comment: @Dingo13: as said in the comments, it is $\approx\frac{n}{\log(n)^3}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio that might look nice due to the exponentials.  Or you've already calculated that...

Comment: Thank you again. Why do you use $\approx$ for asymptotic?

Comment: @Dingo13 he uses it as an approximation.  But I suppose it's also an asymptote.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Can we use asymptotic equivalence?

Comment: @Dingo13 yes, Jack's result fits nicely if that's what you aimed for.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Ok, thank you again !

Comment: No problem! :-)